# KeePass Installation

Tags: software-installation

I'm fairly new to elementary OS and Linux in general - love it so far. I just installed Loki and I am reinstalling the apps I had on Freya. What's the proper way to install KeePass. I had it installed in Freya and frankly I don't remember how I did it! I think it was through the Freya app center. I don't see it in the Loki app center and my Google searches do not offer a definitive answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can install it  from terminal `sudo apt install keepassx`. I did it that way as I was unable to find it in App Center.

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution - worked just fine for me too.